# How to execute oracle copy command from c#? I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to copy a table from from remote oracle database to my to another oracle database. From sql developer it work's fine but when i run the command in C# it show's an error.

```
command.CommandText = "COPY FROM my_username/my_password@schemaname  REPLACE USR_TYPE  USING SELECT * FROM DMS_PREPROD.DAT_PORTAL_USER_ROLE_VW";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It throw the error: *{"ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"}*

Comment: The same as any other SQL query. The error complains that the *query* is wrong, it has nothing to do with C#

Comment: [COPY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm) isn't a SQL command, it's a SQL*Plus command. According to the docs it's obsolete as well

Comment: Hi Kanavos,Thank's for your reply but as i told earlier when I ran the query in SQL developer it work's fine. But when i run it from a program it show the error. Can you suggest me a way to do this ?

Comment: Please read the comment and the link. That's *not* a PL/SQL command. It only works because the tools you used understand it, intercept it and send the apporpriate SQL statements to Oracle. You won't be able to use it from any other product. It's **Oracle itself** that complains with that `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` error

Comment: In fact, the documentation clearly explains this command is deprecated since Oracle 9i and will be removed eventually. At some point you won't be able to use that command at all